# generate all possible words typed on a phone keypad recursively in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

generate all possible words typed on a phone keypad in javascript,

assume you have access to an api to identify correct words.

EDIT: my memory is very bad so appoligies but I can't remember the exact phrasing, the problem is the same as here: 
http://tianrunhe.wordpress.com/2012/07/27/letter-combinations-of-a-phone-number/

I had a technical test for a job interview recently but was hit by the above question and I think I've failed as recursion is something I've never wrapped my head around.  The question assumes I have access to an api to identify correct words, I have not coded in this part as it's something I can easily add when this works.

I want to understand where I went wrong so I have a better chance next time.  The code I have so far is:

His answer is in java though, not javascript.  I have used this function for a reference but can't get it to work yet.

```
    keypad_mapings =    [
                                [],
                                ['a','b','c'],
                                ['d','e','f'],
                                ['g','h','i'],
                                ['j','k','l'],
                                ['m','n','o'],
                                ['p','q','r','s'],
                                ['t','u','v'],
                                ['w','x','y','z']
                        ];

    get_all_words([1, 2, 3]);


    function get_all_words(pressed_buttons) {
        var letters = [];
        for(i=0; i<pressed_buttons.length; i++) {
            letters.push(keypad_mapings[pressed_buttons[i]]);
        }

        var progress = 0;
        current_word = '';
        limit = pressed_buttons.length;
        found_words = [];

        var return_value = recursive_word_generator(letters, progress, current_word, limit, found_words);
        console.log(return_value);
    }


    function recursive_word_generator(letters, progress, current_word, limit, found_words) {

        // I expect this to only be zero in first iteration, all recursive calls should be incremented to some degree
        console.log(progress);

        if(current_word.length >= limit) {
            if(current_word.length == limit){
                found_words.push(current_word);
            }
            return found_words;
        }else{
            //itterating button presses
            for(i=0; i<letters.length; i++) {
                current_letters = letters[i];
                console.log(current_letters);
                for(i = progress; i<letters.length; i++) {
                    current_word = current_word.concat(current_letters[i]);
                    found_words = recursive_word_generator(letters.slice(1), i, current_word, limit, found_words);
                }
            }
        }
        return found_words
    }
```

EDIT: I am now getting the first 3 results correctly, however the recursion doesn't seem to be working, I would expect the progress variable to increment inside the recursion but when I log it its value is always 0.  I feel like I'm so close to a correct answer...

Comment: is that the exact phrasing?  It seems kinda weird.

Comment: I'll edit the question and try to be more accurate (I cant see the question anymore)

Comment: Assuming that the DICT is stored on the server, it would be utterly stupid to recursively ping the server over and over again to see if a word exists, where it should just be pinged with the letters and then the server would just do a select for top 10 that start with the letters entered.  They you would easily have up to 10 words you could display for the "auto complete".  Its not terrible though, in this way to resolve it, just make whatever edits you need quick, and ill try to write up a solution. :)

Comment: for the sake of the question once it's working I'm going to write a function that returns true no matter what in place of the imaginary api call.

Comment: The link you gave had the answer in 2 different languages.  You need it converted to Javascript?  that's rather straight forward.

Comment: I did try to convert it myself (the code I posted was that attempt) but was having trouble wrapping my head around recursion, I was seeing two nested loops and that threw me.  The answer given here has shown me where I was going wrong.  It wasn't really working code I was looking for, I wanted to understand what was going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the place you really went wrong was in your loop.  You are looping over each key press in your recursive function.  However, each call to the recursive function should really handle a single key press.  The loop should instead be over the possible letters for the key press being processed in that call:

http://jsfiddle.net/8rLvM/

```
function recursive_word_generator(letters, progress, current_word, limit, found_words) {

    if (progress == limit) {
        // completed word, add to collection
        found_words.push(current_word);
    } else {

        // make recursive call for each letter in current press
        for (var i = 0; i < letters[progress].length; i++) {
            var next_word = current_word + letters[progress][i];

            recursive_word_generator(letters, progress + 1, next_word, limit, found_words);
        }
    }

    return found_words
}
```

Comment: A minor note.  You don't really even need to return anything from your function.  You can simply use `found_words` in the calling function once the recursion completes.  I left this out of my answer as it doesn't really affect the issues with your code.  http://jsfiddle.net/8rLvM/1/

Comment: thanks a lot for you excellent answer.  Thanks to you I now know that my mistakes were:

    I wasn't using progress as success trigger in the initial if statment.  
   i in the for loop was a global so was breaking recursion.  
   I was double looping.

I understand what I did wrong now, thats perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for this task. The central part is a `collect` function witch called recursively. It collects whole 'alphabet number' and push each of them to the results array

```js
const codes = {
  2: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  3: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
  4: ['g', 'h', 'i'],
  5: ['j', 'k', 'l'],
  6: ['m', 'n', 'o'],
  7: ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'],
  8: ['t', 'u', 'v'],
  9: ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
};

/**
 * @param {string} digits
 * @returns {string[]}
 */
const letterCombinations = (digits) => {
  if (!digits) {
    return [];
  }
  const dLength = digits.length;
  if (dLength === 1) {
    return codes[digits];
  }

  const results = [];

  const collect = (str) => {
    if (str.length === dLength) {
      results.push(str);
      return;
    }
    const digit = digits[str.length];
    for (const el of codes[digit]) {
      collect(str + el);
    }
  };
  collect('');

  return results;
};
```